# Tooltip using javascript and html on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

JS function:

```
function DisplayToolTip() {
    document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.left = window.event.x;
    document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.top = window.event.y;
    document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function HideToolTip() {
    document.getElementById('divToolTip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="spanName" style="font-weight: bold;border: solid 2px red;" onmouseover="javascript:DisplayToolTip();" onmouseout="javascript:HideToolTip();">
    THIS IS THE SPAN
</span>

<div id="divToolTip" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 20; background-color: white; border: solid 1px Blue;">
    This is ToolTip Text
</div>
```

With this I got a JS error that is `window.event.x is not defined`. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If you're not doing this as a learning exercise, I'd suggest using qTip2, as it saves re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: It is not defined cause in your `DisplayToolTip` function you use `event` var, which should be passed to it as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery in this method

```
jQuery(".abc").mousedown(function(e){ 
        jQuery('#divToolTip').css('top',(e.pageY)+'px');
        jQuery('#divToolTip').css('left',(e.pageX)+'px');
        jQuery('#divToolTip').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```